# Why should anonymous types cannot be passed around methods?

Tags: c#

What is the design decision to lean towards not returning an anonymous types from a method?

Comment: because we would be back with VB's variant type! ;)

Comment: maybe because people won't declare anything called "data type" while writing code and code reviewer could go bald!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* return an instance of an anonymous type from a method - but because you can't name it, you can't declare exactly what the method will return, so you'd have to declare that it returns just `object`. That means the caller won't have statically typed access to the properties etc - although they could still pass the instance around, access it via reflection (or dynamic typing in C# 4).

Personally I would quite like a future version of C# to allow you to write a very brief class declaration which generates the same code (immutable properties, constructor, Equals/GetHashcode/ToString) with a name...

There is *one* grotty hack to go round it, called [casting by example](http://tomasp.net/articles/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx). I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: ...you can have that with CodeRush today, very handy. Is there any reason you want this to be included in the language rather than VS?

Comment: @Johannes: Yes, maintainability. I want to be able to maintain the *simple* form. The *ability* to expand the type into its full code so I can then add extra functionality is certainly handy, but there's more to it than that. To give another example, imagine if we didn't have the `using` statement, but VS macros which would generate the equivalent try/finally blocks - would that be just as good as having the using `statement` in the language, in your view?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So you're basically proposing a "data only class" construct?

Comment: @Johannes: Yup. Possibly in an *ideal* world you could then add extra methods (but not fields) without expanding it - although extension methods would do the same thing, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Because an anonymous type has no name. Therefore you cannot declare a return type for a method.

Answer (score 1):

Because C# is statically typed language and in a statically typed language the return type of a method needs to be known at compile time and anonymous types have no names.

Answer (score 1):

How can you use your type inside your method if the definition is only in the call of the method ?

It's not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of answers heere seem to indicatie that it is not possible because of the current syntax and rule. But the question is about changing them. I think it would be possible, but a little complicated and resulting in an awkward (error-prone) syntax. Like

```
var f() { return new { A = "*", B = 1 }; }

var x = f();
```

The question is whether this adds sufficient value to the language to make it worth it.

Comment: First off, "var" means "variable", so I would feel bad about making a return type, which is not a variable, say "var". Second, this would greatly complicate the design of the compiler. Doable, but rather a lot more work than one would naively think. See http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx for some thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

At least up to 3.5, anonymous types are actually resolved at compile time, and this would be impossible (or quite hard) to do with anonymous method signatures.