# Upcasting an IEnumerable<object> in controller?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using a repository for my models like this

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetDetailList(int userId, int page, int rp, string sortname, string sortorder, ref int num, ref int numpg)
{
    var details = (from access in context.erp_sec_companyaccesses
                   join company in context.erp_maint_companies on Convert.ToInt32(access.company_id) equals company.company_id
                   where access.user_id == userId
                   select new
                   {
                       pkey = access.company_access_id,
                       company_access_id = access.company_access_id,
                       company_code = company.company_code,
                       company_name = company.company_name,
                       company_id = company.company_id
                   });

    num = details.Count();
    numpg = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)(num / rp));

    details = details.OrderBy(sortname+" "+sortorder).Skip(page * rp).Take(rp);

    return details;
}
```

But I'm struggling to upcast the `IEnumerable<object>` returned to the controller. Is there any alternative than this ?

Update : I give up up-casting, I'll send a typed object instead of anonymous, thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

You should not be passing around anonymous objects. I have tried doing it yesterday and did not find an easy solution. So the best thing to do is create another class for your data.

Here is the answer from Skeet: [Why should anonymous types cannot be passed around methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400508/why-should-anonymous-types-cannot-be-passed-around-methods)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you probably want to create a concrete type e.g. `Details` and return an `IEnumerable<Details>` from your function rather than an `IEnumerable<object>`.

I'm assuming this because it appears you probably want to access the fields of your anonymous type created inside the function elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass the Object type you want to your method and returning this?